Error in the text of the LGPL 3.0 linking exception
I have found an error in the text of the LGPL 3.0 linking exception, as follows:

As a special exception ...providing any... Minimal Application Code...

There is no “Minimal Application Code” in LGPL 3.0, only Corresponding Application Code. I contacted SPDX but they say they only reflect licenses as they are found in the wild, which includes the error. They don't advise or correct. There doesn't seem to be an authoritative source like the FSF, which could credibly update the license.
Does anyone have any suggestions about how to address this?

Is there some particular project that uses this licence whose code you were hoping to use under those terms?

Yes there is a project that wants to use this exception. They're planning to use the corrected text (referring to Corresponding Application Code) but also want to include the SPDX identifier.

The project could consider offering both exceptions, with the legacy version just so that the SPDX identifier can be used. Later, if use of the fixed version meets the SPDX "substantial use" criterion, it could be assigned its own SPDX identifier or could be merged into the LGPL-3.0-linking-exception text via a "replaceable section" that allows both alternatives.
